# Netbeans 8.0.2 cannot find my top level class

Tags: java, netbeans

Using NB 8.0.2, every now and again it seems to lose track of my top level class, and asks me to select one from a list.  Problem is, the list is empty.  I can run the program by selecting the top-most class in the editor and using Shift-F6, but it doesn't build the whole project, and I can't find a way to make it (selecting the Build menu option prompts me with the same empty list).
Usually, it "remembers" it again if I restart it; but not always, and I'd like a way to make it do so more reliably.

Answer (score 0):

By "top level class", I assume you mean main class. That is the class with a public static void main(String args[]) function that gets called to start the program running.

Assuming this is a normal Java Application project with a build.xml file, the main class can be set by right-clicking on the project, choosing properties from the pop-up menu, selecting run on the side of the dialog, and entering the class name with the full package path in the Main class text field.This may be more reliable but I am not sure.

If you have compile errors, your main function doesn't exactly match that main function signature or for example a missed placed brace could make it not find your main, and therefore empty box. You could look for the red bars on the side of the editor, or compile the file(F9) to check.

Please comment on this answer if it is not sufficient.

Comment: The main class text field is already set correctly when I choose the run properties as you've suggested above.  (Incidentally, if I try to browse for the answer using the button to the right of the text field, I see the same blank dialogue box as I do when I try to run).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help - for what it's worth I've found the answer elsewhere: I had to close NB, delete the cache directory (~/.cache/netbeans/index), and restart.